# Prove by direct proof that for all positive integer $n$, if 30 divides $n^2$ then $30$ divides $n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am a little bit lost with this one since the textbook my class have been using never dealt with $n^2$ in a proof like this. I have found answers for question similar to this where instead of $30$ it is $3$ but they use proof by contra-position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^2$ means that for all the prime factors in $n$, the exponents are doubled in $n^2$.

$30$ has prime factorization $30 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$, all of which are exponent $1$. If those primes are found in $n^2$ when all the exponents are $2$ or greater, they will also be found in $n$ when you cut all the exponents in half.

It's not only just true for $30$ for for any squarefree integer as well.